# Get dynamic model properties list for Razor template

Tags: razor, template-engine

I'm looking into the [RazorEngine](http://nuget.org/packages/RazorEngine) for an e-mail templating system.

The system wil have lots of different e-mail templates so I don't want to create a typed model for each and every template.

Is it somehow possible to use a dynamic model and to retrieve a list of all the properties the dynamic model should have?

For example:

**View/template**

```
@model dynamic

Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum @Model.Customer Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum
Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum @Model.Product Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum
```

From that View/template I want to be able to retrieve the following list (before calling Razor.Parse):
*Customer*
*Product*

With that list I will able to create my dynamic model (containing Customer en Product properties) that can be used in the call to Razor.Parse.

Is this possible and if so how do I do this? Are there alternatives?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

If you know enough about the model to know that it has a Customer and a Product than you should probably use a base class that all your email items inherit:

```
public class EmailItem
{
    public string Customer {get;set;}
    public string Product {get;set;}
}
```

And then use that as your model.

Then the item you pass in can be like so:

```
public class Sale: EmailItem
{
    // inherits EmailItem properties...
}
```